# Gatekeeper rejects my application bundle

Tags: macos, signature, signing, codesign

I'm completely puzzled by Apple signature system. It drives me nuts.

I have a Qt app (so not going through the XCode ecosystem) that I'm signing manually on macOS 10.12.

After signing, I run codesign --verify --deep --strict --verbose=2 PATHTOAPP as recommended here: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2206/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007919-CH1-TNTAG211

And I get:

> valid on disk
>   satisfies its Designated Requirement

Which is the expected, valid result.

When I do codesign -dv --verbose=4 PATHTOAPP I get:

> Authority=Developer ID Application: MYAPPLEID Authority=Developer ID
>   Certification Authority Authority=Apple Root CA
>   Sealed Resources version=2

When I run it against the check-signature tool provided by Apple, I get a YES meaning it's correctly signed.

But when I run it against spctl -a -t exec -vv PATHTOAPP I get a:

> rejected (embedded framework contains modified or invalid version)

And in the end, Gatekeeper rejects my app

Unfortunately the spctl utility doesn't give me a clue about what's wrong and where to look at.
I don't get it, since codesign with the deepest and strictest flags says it's ok.

Any idea on how I can get more information ?

**EDIT1:** I ran spctl --assess --raw --verbose PATHTOAPP and I get this:

```
<key>assessment:authority</key>
<dict>
    <key>assessment:authority:flags</key>
    <integer>0</integer>
    <key>assessment:authority:source</key>
    <string>obsolete resource envelope</string>
    <key>assessment:authority:weak</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
<key>assessment:cserror</key>
<integer>-67009</integer>
<key>assessment:remote</key>
<true/>
<key>assessment:verdict</key>
<false/>
```

Now I don't know what to believe, is it "embedded framework contains modified or invalid version" or is it "obsolete resource envelope" (and why) ?

When I check error codes here: https://github.com/CamJN/Security/blob/77b26b3e434caec74403da43bcfb02532a25d7ff/libsecurity_codesigning/lib/CSCommon.h

I see:

```
errSecCSWeakResourceRules =         -67013, /* resource envelope is obsolete */
errSecCSBadFrameworkVersion =       -67009, /* embedded framework contains modified or invalid version */
```

**EDIT2:** It's really the contents of my Frameworks folder that is causing the problem. When I delete everything in-there before signing, it passes spctl validation.

The problem is, if I just let one single, pure Framework such as QtCore (from Qt 5.7.0) I immediatly gets the spctl error:

> rejected (embedded framework contains modified or invalid version)

Comment: If you use `macdeployqt`, you can use the `-codesign` argument and have it sign the bundle for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out the content of each framework missed the FRAMEWORK.framework/Versions/Current symlink

Required symlinks:

```
FRAMEWORK.framework/Resources
FRAMEWORK.framework/Versions/Current
```

Easy script to create thoses symlinks (while in the Frameworks folder):

```
find . -path '*.framework/Versions/[0-9]' -and -not -type l -print0 | while read -d $'\0' FRMPATH
    do
        ln -s ${FRMPATH/*framework\//}/Resources $FRMPATH/../../Resources
        ln -s ${FRMPATH/*Versions\//} $FRMPATH/../Current
    done
```

I also discovered a command that makes Gatekeeper accept self-signed certificate (useful when you don't have an Apple Developer ID but need to test against spctl):

```
spctl --add --requirement "certificate leaf[subject.CN] = \"MY CERTIFICATE\"" --label "MyCustomCertificate"
```

(where MY CERTIFICATE must be replaced with the name of your own, self-signed/self-generated certificate)